# Bluetooth turns on but won't connect to devices Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I'm experiencing some issues with the Bluetooth interface on my Asus laptop.

Bluetooth seems to be turned on, but it can't connect devices.
I tried updating kernel from 4.15 to 4.17, but nothing changed.

When I type `sudo service bluetooth status` this is printed on terminal:

```
giu 16 12:38:43  bluetoothd[1052]: Bluetooth daemon 5.48
giu 16 12:38:43  bluetoothd[1052]: Starting SDP server
giu 16 12:38:43  systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
giu 16 12:38:45  bluetoothd[1052]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
giu 16 12:39:22  bluetoothd[1052]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.81 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
giu 16 12:39:22 bluetoothd[1052]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.81 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
giu 16 12:40:21 bluetoothd[1052]: Can't get HIDP connection info
giu 16 12:40:52 bluetoothd[1052]: connect error: Connection timed out (110)
giu 16 15:37:48 bluetoothd[1052]: Can't get HIDP connection info
giu 16 15:38:29 bluetoothd[1052]: connect error: Connection refused (111)
```

I read about other users with my same problem, but their solutions are not working on my PC.

Any suggestions?

Update:

Output of: `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 058f:a014 Alcor Micro Corp. Asus Integrated Webcam
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 13d3:3362 IMC Networks Atheros AR3012 Bluetooth 4.0 Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.008379] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.208143] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    2.096248] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[    2.400163] psmouse serio4: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x361f03)
[   26.328376] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   26.328393] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   26.328396] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   26.328398] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   26.328403] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   39.475242] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[   39.701739] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   39.701740] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   39.701744] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   42.656101] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2009 tx timeout
[   44.704046] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c13 tx timeout
[   46.752042] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c52 tx timeout
[   48.800093] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c24 tx timeout
[10001.058969] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[10001.058980] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[10001.104634] input: Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:21/0005:05AC:0239.0005/input/input30
[10001.105356] apple 0005:05AC:0239.0005: input,hidraw4: BLUETOOTH HID v1.1b Keyboard [Bluetooth 3.0 Keyboard] on dc:85:de:19:18:37
[10860.307550] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[10860.307563] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[10860.307568] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: sorry, i'm currently using 18.04, i had a mistake while typing. Gonna correct it.

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: I copied all the terminal output.